# msw server post request not returning body

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, msw

Here's how I'm setting up the server

```
const server = setupServer(
    http.post('http://172.17.0.1:3001/auth/confirm', async ({ request }) => {
        const newPost = await request.json() as Request;

        return HttpResponse.json({ body: newPost }, { status: 400 });
    })
);
```

I'm setting up my tests with

```
beforeAll(() => server.listen());
render(<ConfirmationPage />);
```

The component makes the request on load with

```
axios.post('http://172.17.0.1:3001/auth/confirm', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, responseType: 'json'
}).then(response => {
    console.log('here success', response);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('here error', error);
});
```

But the response is coming back with an empty string for data

```
{ data: '', status: 400 ...}
```

The only other info I can think of is the testEnvironment in jest is `jest-environment-jsdom` and the setupFiles is the following

```
const { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } = require('util');
const { Response } = require('whatwg-fetch');

global.Response = Response;

global.TextEncoder = TextEncoder;
global.TextDecoder = TextDecoder;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems when updating my msw package from 0.39 to the latest. I was able to change the status of the response but the body would always be an empty string. Looking at their [docs](https://mswjs.io/docs/migrations/1.x-to-2.x/#frequent-issues) for frequent issues it shows to install the 'undici' library to define global properties. I was using the latest 6.2.0 version of 'undici' when I should have been using an earlier major version, so switching to 5.2.0 instead fixed the issue for me